# how to break all external links in google sheets and save values only backup with date as name of file automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to break all external links in google sheets and save/archive values only backup with date as name of file automatically?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You weren't super clear, but it would be something like this (say your urls are in column C);

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sh.getSheetByName("data");
var data = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
    var url = data[2].getValue();
    ss.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(url);
    }//for loop
```

This isn't the fastest way to do it but it is very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for above answer. Suppose I have one google sheet file which uses importrange function and query function to get data from other linked google sheets and do some calculation on top of that to get the output. I want to have one duplicate copy made of that google sheet in form of google sheet with no links to other google sheets and has values only without any formulas. By linking I mean connection to other g sheets by importrange or query function. @J.G.